# Java code suddenly stop

Tags: java

Ive got a problem.I 'm new to Java,I've started today:D) ..I've programmed before so I know it little bit,but I am new to Java. Here is my code: `

```
public class Tutorial {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    double num1,num2;
    String operacia;
    Scanner in=new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.println("Write 2 numbers");
    num1=in.nextDouble();
    num2=in.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Choose the operation");
    operacia=in.nextLine();
    if (operacia.equals("+")){
        System.out.println("Your result is "+(num1+num2))   ;
    }
    else if (operacia.equals("-")){
        System.out.println("Your result is  "+(num1-num2))  ;
    }
    else if (operacia.equals("/")){
        System.out.println("Your result is  "+(num1/num2))  ;
    }
    else if (operacia.equals("*")){
        System.out.println("Your result is  "+(num1*num2))  ;
    }




}
}`
```

It wants from me 2 numbers,I write them and them it writes "Choose the operation" and its over.No more inputs.Thank you very much :)

Comment: Add `else{ System.out.print( "[" + operacia+ "]" ) }` in the end, so that you can know what is `operacia`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is simple.

Just replace the code with next() instead of nextLine().Effectively, the line your code is returning is receiving is a blank line. Hence when it reaches the conditional statement it has an empty string and terminates.

```
next()
Finds and returns the next complete token from this scanner.

nextLine()
Advances this scanner past the current line and returns the input that was skipped.
```

Your code should be fixed by a simple change.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    double num1,num2;
    String operacia;

    Scanner in=new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.println("Write 2 numbers");

    num1=in.nextDouble();
    num2=in.nextDouble();

    System.out.println("Choose the operation");
    operacia=in.next();

    if (operacia.equals("+")){
        System.out.println("Your result is "+(num1+num2))   ;
    }
    else if (operacia.equals("-")){
        System.out.println("Your result is  "+(num1-num2))  ;
    }
    else if (operacia.equals("/")){
        System.out.println("Your result is  "+(num1/num2))  ;
    }
    else if (operacia.equals("*")){
        System.out.println("Your result is  "+(num1*num2))  ;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Scanner#nextDouble()` consumes only the next token as a double from the input. It does not consume the new line you typed using the <kbd>Enter</kbd> on the keyboard while entering the two numbers. When the execution reaches `operacia=in.nextLine();`, this new line is consumed, never allowing the user a chance to type the operating string.

To solve this, you need to read the whole line using `Scanner#nextLine()` and convert it to a double:

```
String input = in.nextLine();
num1 = Double.parseDouble(input);
input = in.nextLine();
num2 = Double.parseDouble(input);
```

Answer (score -1):

I believe the in.nextLine(); operation is reading only to the end of the line where you input 2 numbers. If you want your program to only consider the next line, you have to clear the current one first.

Try this, it should work:

```
System.out.println("Choose the operation");
in.nextLine(); //clear the current line
operacia=in.nextLine();
```